# volumesnapshotcontent created with old timestamp

Tags: kubernetes, snapshot, persistent-volumes

I have a scenario where volumesnapshotcontent is getting created with weird timestamp.

```
snapcontent-f5dae7f1-5fcc-4b10-a856-27462e8f248a   false        1073741824    Retain           vpc.block.csi.ibm.io   stork-csi-snapshot-class-vpc.block.csi.ibm.io   px-do-not-delete-cf058705-d4ea-4da8-b8e4-d8602a160acc-0e1b8534   kube-system               36d
```

Here Age is 36d. Is there a reason for this

Comment: Hi @ambikanair, I have been looking for your response whether the info shared by me was helpful to you. I am glad to assist you further if you have any additional queries or the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [VolumeSnapshotContent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/#introduction) is a snapshot taken from a volume in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator. It is a resource in the cluster just like a PersistentVolume is a cluster resource. `The timestamp associated with a ‘VolumeSnapshotContent’ resource might not always reflect the exact creation time by system.` It does not update automatically when the object is modified or created.

When a `VolumeSnapshotContent` is created, GCP assigns a timestamp to the resource based on when snapshot content was generated.  Snapshot content was provisioned before registering the VolumeSnapshotContent into kubernetes. **So, VSC might take the timestamp of snapshot content creation.** Later on, in the "binding" section, End-users creates their VolumeSnapshot. Then admin proceeds with snapshotting data, and eventually registers a VSC and binds it to the end-user's VolumeSnapshot.

Ensure the configuration within your `kubernetes cluster` or `storage system` you are providing is correct or not This might cause the incorrect timestamp in creation.

To troubleshoot further, please provide more specific details like the kubernetes version, storage system.